# Installing Homebrew, libjpeg, and optipng for HTML5 Boilerplate build tool use

Tags: optimization, html, command-line, terminal, homebrew

Dipping my toe into command prompts.. totally lost.

I've installed Homebrew, and attempted to install libjpeg and optipng via `brew install libjpeg optipng`and have run into errors. I'm not sure how exactly to describe them.. so here's the code! I'm in Terminal on a Mac running OSX 10.6.7

Thank you SO much for the help.

```
1961:~ Daniel$ brew install libjpeg optipng
==> Downloading http://www.ijg.org/files/jpegsrc.v8c.tar.gz
File already downloaded and cached to /Users/Daniel/Library/Caches/Homebrew
==> ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/jpeg/8c --disable-dependency-tracking
checking build system type... i386-apple-darwin10.7.3
checking host system type... i386-apple-darwin10.7.3
checking target system type... i386-apple-darwin10.7.3
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... ./install-sh -c -d
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... no
checking for nawk... no
checking for awk... awk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... no
checking for style of include used by make... none
checking for gcc... /usr/bin/cc
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/private/tmp/homebrew-jpeg-8c-42or/jpeg-8c':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
==> Exit Status: 77
http://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/blob/master/Library/Formula/jpeg.rb#L11
==> Environment
HOMEBREW_VERSION: 0.8
HEAD: (none)
HOMEBREW_PREFIX: /usr/local
HOMEBREW_CELLAR: /usr/local/Cellar
HOMEBREW_REPOSITORY: /usr/local
HOMEBREW_LIBRARY_PATH: /usr/local/Library/Homebrew
Hardware: 8-core 64-bit dunno
OS X: 10.6.7
Kernel Architecture: x86_64
Ruby: 1.8.7-174
/usr/bin/ruby => /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby
Xcode: 
GCC-4.0: N/A 
GCC-4.2: N/A 
LLVM: build 2335 
MacPorts or Fink? false
X11 installed? true
==> Build Flags
CC: /usr/bin/cc
CXX: /usr/bin/c++
LD: /usr/bin/cc
CFLAGS: -O3 -w -pipe -arch i386 -arch x86_64
CXXFLAGS: -O3 -w -pipe -arch i386 -arch x86_64
LDFLAGS: -arch i386 -arch x86_64
MAKEFLAGS: -j8

Error: Failed executing: ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/jpeg/8c --disable-dependency-tracking
Please report this bug: https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/wiki/new-issue
These existing issues may help you:
https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/issues/#issue/4442
It looks like an autotools configure failed.
Consider re-running the install with '-vd' to keep 'config.log' around:
    brew install -vd jpeg
Gist 'config.log' and any error output when reporting an issue.
Remember to include your config information: brew --config

Also try:
  `brew doctor` to check your setup for common problems.
  `brew missing` to check installed packages for missing deps.
1961:~ Daniel$ brew doctor
We couldn't detect gcc 4.2.x. Some formulae require this compiler.

We couldn't detect gcc 4.0.x. Some formulae require this compiler.

/usr/bin is in your PATH before Homebrew's bin. This means that system-
provided programs will be used before Homebrew-provided ones. This is an
issue if you install, for instance, Python.

Consider editing your .bashrc to put:
  /usr/local/bin
ahead of /usr/bin in your $PATH.

Some brews install binaries to sbin instead of bin, but Homebrew's
sbin was not found in your path.

Consider editing your .bashrc to add:
  /usr/local/sbin
to $PATH.

"Git" was not found in your path.

Homebrew uses Git for several internal functions, and some formulae
use Git checkouts instead of stable tarballs.

You may want to do:
  brew install git

You have an "autoconf" in your path blocking the system version at:


Custom autoconf in general and autoconf 2.66 in particular has issues
and will cause some Homebrew formulae to fail.

1961:~ Daniel$ brew install git
==> Downloading http://kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/git-1.7.5.tar.bz2
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> make prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/git/1.7.5 install

==> Exit Status: 1
http://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/blob/master/Library/Formula/git.rb#L31
==> Environment
HOMEBREW_VERSION: 0.8
HEAD: (none)
HOMEBREW_PREFIX: /usr/local
HOMEBREW_CELLAR: /usr/local/Cellar
HOMEBREW_REPOSITORY: /usr/local
HOMEBREW_LIBRARY_PATH: /usr/local/Library/Homebrew
Hardware: 8-core 64-bit dunno
OS X: 10.6.7
Kernel Architecture: x86_64
Ruby: 1.8.7-174
/usr/bin/ruby => /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby
Xcode: 
GCC-4.0: N/A 
GCC-4.2: N/A 
LLVM: build 2335 
MacPorts or Fink? false
X11 installed? true
==> Build Flags
CC: /usr/bin/cc
CXX: /usr/bin/c++
LD: /usr/bin/cc
CFLAGS: -O3 -w -pipe
CXXFLAGS: -O3 -w -pipe
MAKEFLAGS: -j8

Error: Failed executing: make prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/git/1.7.5 install
Please report this bug: https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/wiki/new-issue

Also try:
  `brew doctor` to check your setup for common problems.
  `brew missing` to check installed packages for missing deps.
1961:~ Daniel$ brew missing
1961:~ Daniel$ brew doctor
We couldn't detect gcc 4.2.x. Some formulae require this compiler.

We couldn't detect gcc 4.0.x. Some formulae require this compiler.

/usr/bin is in your PATH before Homebrew's bin. This means that system-
provided programs will be used before Homebrew-provided ones. This is an
issue if you install, for instance, Python.

Consider editing your .bashrc to put:
  /usr/local/bin
ahead of /usr/bin in your $PATH.

Some brews install binaries to sbin instead of bin, but Homebrew's
sbin was not found in your path.

Consider editing your .bashrc to add:
  /usr/local/sbin
to $PATH.

"Git" was not found in your path.

Homebrew uses Git for several internal functions, and some formulae
use Git checkouts instead of stable tarballs.

You may want to do:
  brew install git

You have an "autoconf" in your path blocking the system version at:


Custom autoconf in general and autoconf 2.66 in particular has issues
and will cause some Homebrew formulae to fail.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try downloading and installing the Xcode development suite: http://developer.apple.com/xcode/

That will provide gcc (complier) to build the software

Comment: Have you looked at the config.log? 

# more ~/config.log